# Android app icon click takes too much time to open

Tags: android, performance, splash-screen

On clicking on android app icon, app takes lot of time to open and then white screen appears before launching MainActivity.

splash_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/splash_screen"
        android:gravity="center" />
</layer-list>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="LauncherLogoTheme" theme="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/sdp_launcher_background</item>
    </style>
```

manifest file

```
<activity
                    android:name=".SplashActivity"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                    android:noHistory="true"
                    android:theme="@style/LauncherLogoTheme">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
```

SplashScreenActivity

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Please help on how to use splash screen in a correct way

Comment: Are you have heavy operations in MainActivity?

Comment: The white screen appears before or after the splash screen?

Answer (score 1):

If you have seen some apps using a splash screen, you must have noticed that they stay on the splash screen for 1 or half a second. Which is a standard for a splash screen. Mostly splash screen is white and an image generally with app icon/logo and app name.

Coming to your issue; the issue with your code is that you start another activity when the current activity is just created and just after that you are finishing it. I also don't see `setContentView()`.

The recommended approach is to use a `Handler` and use a delayed callback to start the next activity and finish the current one.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        new Handler(Looper.myLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        },1000);
    }
}
```

Delayed starting of next activity and finishing of the current for 1 Second(1000 ms). Which will allow the Splash activity to be created and then resumed(become visible to user) smoothly before it is finished.

Comment: In addition to this I'd say-  if you don't need a splash screen (if you aren't loading a lot of data that requires you to show a UI while doing so)  don't have one.  They add no value to your users and just slow things down.  They make sense only when your app is too slow to load.

Comment: Yes @GabeSechan, But Sometimes people just want to show their logo, but what you suggested is true and this fellow [Inshorts - 60 words News summary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nis.app) does the same, it loads news while showing splash.

Comment: Yes.  Those people are considered jerks.  If you need one for time reasons that's fine-  lots of apps need time to load, authenticate, etc.  If you're showing a logo just to show a logo you're providing a poor experience and annoying your users.

Comment: @GabeSechan A launch screen when not done by having a handler that delays the launch of another activity is not providing poor experience in fact I would say it is providing a better once since on cold starts an app can take a second to load (not including any additional data loading) so all you would see is a blank canvas.

Comment: @tyczj If its actually loading data, its fine.  If its just there to advertise, its doing nothing to provide value to the user and is a negative experience.

Comment: @rahat I don't want to show any app logo but having splash screen to do few things at launch time before opening Main Activity. Also it is recommended not to set setContentView on using styles windowBackground. https://shishirthedev.medium.com/the-right-way-to-implement-a-splash-screen-in-android-acae0e52949a

Comment: @GabeSechan so you just rather show a user a blank screen while the app loads up from a cold start? Please see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5Xu2iNHRkk

Comment: @tyczj I'd rather have the app just load right to a working screen.  If you can't do that, a splash screen may be ok.  But more likely you just coded it badly.  Splash screens have been seen as a negative experience for years.

Comment: @GabeSechan the point I am making is you can have an app that has just two screens that do/load nothing and you will still see a blank screen upon a cold start (albeit very short). Your scenario of loading into a working screen isn't something you can always fix hence the need for a splash screen to show the user something while the app shows

Comment: @tyczj You're not actually reading what I wrote.  If its a necessity, its fine.  If it isn't, it shouldn't exist.  If you're ever showing a blank screen on cold start, its because you didn't program it right-  that's trivial to avoid.  Although its still a better experience than a timed splash screen.  Splash screens for the sake of having one are bad design, period.

Comment: Hello there,As @GabeSechan said, it depends upon if it is necessary, but if you want to have it with or without any necessity then no one is stopping you.